# Using GestureDetector with FlutterFlow

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation, flutterflow

I'm new to FlutterFlow and currently in the process of developing my first app. I'm encountering an issue with two app state variables, namely "posistionX" and "positionY."

I'm attempting to assign the values of these app state variables to the coordinates of the user's tap. The goal is to precisely locate where the user taps on the screen and then set a Lottie widget to that position, triggering its animation.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution without using GestureDetector. Hence, I'm reaching out to seek your assistance with creating custom code to make it work. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried with the onTap actions but there is nothing that can "detect" the user tap position. I think i need to implement GestureDetector in someway to make it work.